# Loading images only when needed

Tags: ios, image, memory, load, uicollectionview

When I load the images to show to the UICollectionView I load all the images from the array like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Others";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionOthers.delegate =self;
    collectionOthers.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent)
    {
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
            NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);
            image = nil;

        }
        finalFilePath=nil;
        data=nil;
    }

    paths= nil;
    documentsDirectory= nil;
    location= nil;
    fPath= nil;
    directoryContent = nil;
}
```

This is the biggest issue in my app since it uses so many memory. It is because  number and size of the images, this could just take up memory.  I would only want to load images when they are needed, and discard them when they are no longer needed.However I do not know where and how to change my code so that it will be that way.  I am doing this for three month or so and I really need help.
**Update**
This is my code for the specific part

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseID = @"ReuseID";
    OthersCell *mycell = (OthersCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[mycell viewWithTag:1];
    imageInCell.image = [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"a");
    return mycell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you should load the images just-in-time. One should never hold an array of images (because they take up a lot of memory), but rather just hold an array of filenames. So I'm suggesting you retire `allImagesArray` and instead define a `NSMutableArray` called `filenames`. You could then create the `UIImage` objects on the fly:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    OthersCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    imageInCell.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filenames[indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}
```

This, assumes, of course, that you populated this `NSMutableArray` of `filenames` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    filenames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Others";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    collectionOthers.delegate =self;
    collectionOthers.dataSource=self;
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent)
    {
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        [filenames addObject:fileFilePath];
    }
}
```

This has a problem, though, because `imageWithContentsOfFile` (as well as loading it into a `NSData` first and then doing `imageWithData`) is a bit slow if the images aren't tiny. On slower devices, this can result in a slight stuttering of a quick scroll of a collection view. So, a better approach would be to (a) load the images asynchronously; (b) use a `NSCache` to optimize performance for when you scroll backwards.

So, first, define a cache:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *imageCache;
```

And, instantiate this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
self.imageCache.name = @"com.company.app.imageCache";
```

And then, `cellForItemAtIndexPath` can (a) set the image from the cache; and (b) if not found, retrieve the image asynchronously updating cache and cell appropriately, e.g.:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    OthersCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    NSString *cacheKey = filenames[indexPath.item];
    imageInCell.image = [self.imageCache objectForKey:cacheKey];

    if (imageInCell.image == nil) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filenames[indexPath.item]];
            if (image) {
                [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:cacheKey];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    OthersCell *updateCell = (id)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[updateCell viewWithTag:1];
                    imageInCell.image = image;
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And, obviously, make sure you purge the cache if you receive memory warnings (in iOS 7, the cache doesn't always automatically purge itself under pressure like it used to do):

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    [self.imageCache removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering just few questions. I get eight errors in the index path.  For example use of undeclared identifier cell, use of undeclared identifier Custom Cell,use of undeclared identifier updatecell,Property objects not found on object of type OthersViewController.

Comment: @user3001507 Those were just my sample custom cell class names and properties, but I've updated my answer to use your variable/class names. By the way, one of the advantages of using custom cell subclasses as you can eliminate that `viewWithTag` stuff, by hooking you `IBOutlet` into the custom cell class. But I've added the unnecessary `viewWithTag` code back in to make it easier for you to read.

Comment: Yes Ive noticed that you replaced my allImagesArray. So filenames is an array?

Comment: Thanks Im almost there. I am getting an error saying Property customImage not found on object of type othercell and Property customImage not found on object of type OthersViewController

Comment: I still can't get rid of the Property customImage not found on object of type OthersViewController

Comment: I am sorry its here it wasnt image but collectionview                    OthersCell *updateCell = (id)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is the method in which you should be loading the images.

In `viewDidLoad`, I'd build the array of `NSString` file paths to each image, then I'd use the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method to load the image from the specific file path for this particular cell.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! Just wrote about the same answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` You could just load a list of available images. So remove the for loop: `for(NSString *str in directoryContent) { ... }` loop there **(EDIT: or make it a simple `for` loop, just to populate an array with filenames for the files having data)**.

When you update a specific collectionviewcell in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, just load the image (only 1). The cell will now hold the image data instead of your view controller. So when the cell is released, so is the image data.

Comment: `for(NSString *str in directoryContent) { ... }` is the loop in which he's loading a list of available images.  He doesn't need to gut this entire loop...

Comment: No, the list is already there before the loop starts in `directoryContent`. He's loading the images in the loop, so he should move that logic to the delegate method and forget the whole loop in `viewDidLoad`!

Comment: Well, after a better look, it seems you are actually right. Because he's filtering out files without data, he might need the loop with just 1 `if` statement to populate the array.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for answering!I am getting really confused because I am new to iOS I have posted my line for the indexpath.  Also I don't really get your answer. sorry..

Comment: I can post an example later today as i have to go now, because i see some other issues as well. You're not calling `[super viewDidLoad]`, `directoryContentsAtPath:` is deprecated, you're currently loading all files having data (not only images).